Grafana panel showing just the filtered variables
Grafana 10.4.3
I have a requirement where I need to display only the values available in the filter Variable and show them in a different panel.
for example I want to show 3 of the values available in the filter list in a different panel. I have added those values as part of custom variables and are the correct/required number of topics that I want the user to know
(https://i.sstatic.net/82WvjDkT.png)
I have prometheus and loki data sources configured only . I understand there is no direct way to do this but is it possible to achieve this with some workaround.
I also tried something like
metrics{query that fetches no result} OR on() $connector:text
but the above doesn't seem to work.

Also to update, i found a way to list the filter values with query as below, but this lists all the available values but i want to filter further and display based on some pattern. label_replace (label_replace(metrics{query}, "name1", "$1", "name", "(.?)(sil)(.)"), "name2", "${connectors:value}", "name", "(.+)")

I don't get what you are trying to do. You have dashboard variable with 7 values. But you want show only 3 of then on a panel? How those 3 supposed to be selected? Do you want/can use multi-value option for your variable? Is there a metric that has those values as labels (guaranteed to have at least one time series at any moment)?

Hi @markalex, example i have some custom filter variables set as example (town1-city1,town1-city2,town2-city1,town2-city2.) and in the filter selection i need to keep it as 'All'. Now provided a metrics with label selected with value town1 and returns values as town1-city2 , then i know town1-city1 is also a expected value which is not being returned by metrics and the user needs to be displayed Missing Value: town1-citi1 in a Panel.
